# Why is the code implemented like this ahout select in golang

Tags: go, prometheus

```
for {
    select {
    case <-n.ctx.Done():
    return
    case ts := <-tsets:
    n.reload(ts)
    default:
        select {
    case <-n.ctx.Done():
        return
    case ts := <-tsets:
        n.reload(ts)
    case <-n.more:
        }
    }
}
```

the code above is in https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/notifier/notifier.go Function Run(tsets <-chan map[string][]*targetgroup.Group). Why default write select again, Dose it has any difference with the following code

```
for {
    select {
    case <-n.ctx.Done():
    return
    case ts := <-tsets:
    n.reload(ts)
    case <-n.more:
    }
}
```

I want to know the difference between these two implementation methods and their impact. thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical implementation of channel priority. If both `<-tsets` and `<-n.more` are available, the first code snipped gives priority to `<-tsets`. In fact, it will loop as long as `<-tsets` can be executed, and then it will start looking at `<-n.more`. Note that the only way the `default` case is selected is if `<-tsets` cannot run and context is not canceled. When that happens, it looks at `<-n.more`.